# Telegram-бот не реагирует на команды. Python

Tags: python, telebot

вопрос очень тупой, но я не знаю как его решить. Делаю первого бота-повторялку по инструкции хауди хо https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8fhrtvedHA. Повторил все в точности как у него, ошибок нет, но бот ничего не отвечает.

```
import telebot
import config

TOKEN = ' не хочу палить токен' # bot token from @BotFather
bot = telebot.telebot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.mesage_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala (mesage):
    bot.send_mesegge (messege.chat.id, mesage.text)

#RUN 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

bot = telebot.telebot(config.TOKEN)

Тут config зачем нужен? Надо просто токен написать и всё. Вместо token можешь просто скопировать адрес и поставить:

bot = telebot.telebot(' не хочешь палить токен')

вот так будет ботат.

Comment: import telebot bot = telebot.telebot(' ') @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) def lalala (message): bot.send_message (message.chat.id, message.text) #RUN bot.polling(none_stop=True) так должно получиться?

Answer (score 0):

```
TOKEN = ' не хочу палить токен' # bot token from @BotFather
bot = telebot.telebot(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже у вас проблемы с английским

```
import telebot

TOKEN = '' # bot token from @BotFather
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala (message):
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, message.text)

#RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: я так только тут по ошибке написал, в самом коде все правильно, но все равно не работает. Я думаю проблема в библиотеке.

Comment: Проблема, скорее всего, у вас. Я проверил и всё работает.

Comment: какую библиотеку вы используете? И какую версию питона?

Comment: Библиотека telebot, python 3.8